# MySql Join tables using aggregate(min) in where condition, without subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I am trying to get one table, along with the lowest value of a column of another table by LEFT JOIN. I am using subquery to do this.

Sample Snippet:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
JOIN
  (select A_id,
          MIN(id) AS complete_date
   from C
   group by A_id) B ON (A.id=B.A_id)
WHERE A.status="complete";
```

Is there any possible and efficient way to achieve this without subquery and group by.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Rewriting to remove a subquery is a faq. Please before considering posting read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask], [Help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.  [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) Please in code questions give a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

A correlated subquery -- with the right indexes -- is often the fastest approach:

```
SELECT A.*,
       (SELECT MIN(C.id)
        FROM C
        WHERE A.id = C.A_id
       ) as complete_date
FROM A
WHERE A.status = 'complete;
```

This avoids the aggregation on an entire table, which is why there is a performance gain.

The index you need is on `C(A_Id, id)` (the second column is not as important as the first).  You may also want an index on `A(status)`.

Comment: thanks for your reply which really helps, can you please explain how can I get the record for this min(C.id) along with this select.

Comment: @KarthikeyanKR . . . That is not the question you asked.  But you would use this as a subquery and join again to `C`.